How to create a user with a Entra ID Role pre-assigned?
One can create a user in Graph using /users API. However, the request body doesn't support specification of any roles the user should be assigned.
  {
  "accountEnabled": true,
  "displayName": "My Name",
  "mailNickname": "MyName",
  "userPrincipalName": "MyName@contoso.com",
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
    "password": "****"
  }

There is a /roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments that does allow role assignments. But I was wondering if there is a way to do this in one go that I am not aware of?
I am looking to assign one of the built-in Entra ID roles.

Can't be done in one way. Also be aware, that if you try to immediately add a user to a role after creating her, it can happen, that you get back a not found error and you have to wait maybe just a few seconds or up to 5 minutes, till all systems know the new user id.

Sorry, this is not possible. You will need the newly created user ID for later ops.
